# Launch Tool is missing in IBM Watson Natural understanding when creating custom model

Tags: nlp, ibm-watson, watson-nlu, watson-knowledge-studio

I am facing a weird issue. I am trying to create a custom model in IBM Watson natural language understanding with lite plan.No launch tool option is shown to create custom model. To be clear, ideallly the page should be like this as described in all the tutorials,

[image]

But What I am getting is

[image]

I tried all possibilities there is no way to navigate to the annotator tool page. Please somebody help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first pic looks Watson Knowledge Studio. Watson Knowledge Studio is a different service you can also create IBM Cloud Catalog. Please check it.
https://www.ibm.com/watson/services/knowledge-studio/

Comment: I have tried creating the project in Watson knowledge studio also. Again I ended up in the same page with no way to proceed for the tool

Comment: After launching your Watson Knowledge Studio, you will see a "Create Workspace" button to build your model. For further details, see https://console.bluemix.net/docs/services/watson-knowledge-studio/index.html#build-a-machine-learning-model   Please note that the current WKS call your working space as "Workspace", not "Project".

Comment: Got it thanks. It’s there when launching from Watson studio in catalog but not when launched using direct url little confusing.